# foreach always repeat first element

Tags: c#, sql-server, foreach

I am trying use a dataset to update a SQL database, I am trying to use a foreach in a dataset, if the element is already in the database catch the error and continue to the next, but the error is always the same:

> "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of PRIMARY
>   KEY constraint 'PK_share1'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.share1'. The duplicate key value is (4008)."

I dont understand why this foreach is always triying insert only 1 element of the dataset instead of continue and find a new one

```
 if (changes != null)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in changes.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        try{
                        adapter.Update(changes);
                        Console.WriteLine("Changes Done");}
                        catch(Exception ex){
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I also tried:

```
 if (changes != null)
                {



                    foreach (DataTable table in changes.Tables)
                    {
                        try{
                        adapter.Update(changes);
                        Console.WriteLine("Changes Done");}
                        catch(Exception ex){
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                            continue;
                        }

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Note that `adapter.Update(changes);` doesn't refer to any Table or Row. It updates the whole DataSet. You don't need a `foreach`.

Comment: Every time you pass same parameter... changes like adapter.Update(changes);

Answer (score 0):

In first code you are iterating through rows, but each time updating whole DataSet. If you want to update DataSet, then you don't need to do it multiple times.

```
if (changes != null)
{
    try
    {
        adapter.Update(changes);
        Console.WriteLine("Changes Done");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

In the second piece of code you are iterating through tables, but updating whole DimSet. To update tables one by one, you should call `adapter.Update(table);` instead of `adapter.Update(changes);`.

```
if (changes != null)
{
    foreach (DataTable table in changes.Tables)
    {
        try
        {
            adapter.Update(table);
            Console.WriteLine("Changes Done");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: to do what I want I had to put:

   if (changes != null)
                        {

                            try
                            {
                                adapter.ContinueUpdateOnError = true;
                                adapter.Update(changes);
                         
                            }

                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

                            }
                        }

Comment: If you set `adapter.ContinueUpdateOnError = true` then errors during a row update will be ignored. I would rather try to prevent those errors instead of just ignoring them.